# Can't edit redirect_uri in SoundCloud app dashboard

Tags: soundcloud

How can I edit the `redirect_uri` in my SoundCloud apps dashboard? I go to http://soundcloud.com/you/apps but no edit button was found.

Answer (score 0):

Editing is not possible at present, and so for now, you'll need to get in touch with the SoundCloud support team to edit this.

Comment: How to get in touch with them? I can't find any support email

Comment: @Shobhit Did you manage to do something about this? My redirect_uri field is always empty, I've even tried creating a new app but it's still empty.

Comment: @damjandd Nope, nothing. The problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

You can review this [enhancement purposal on official Soundcloud API Github Repository](https://github.com/soundcloud/api/issues/44) , this was created on **March 26, 2021** , where SoundCloud official team member accepted that it's a **work in backlog** and you can contact them to make updates to redirect URI.

To resolve this issue, you can **send an email to SoundCloud** at **support@soundcloud.com** to *share the required  changes and the target application for this chang*e.

As of now, they are not providing this feature, due to the security reasons around the authentication connect flow.

Comment: I was able to get ours changed by submitting an issue to the repo: https://github.com/soundcloud/api/issues/79

I emailed support with the specifics but they just directed me to the repo.

Comment: @Ponny yeah, reaching them directly was also an option, its just we would not want the GitHub to be the resolution point to share any app data, when they have mentioned to contact via support email.